# How to select a value from my combobox list?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that populates my combobox with sheet names and updates whenever I click the dropdown button.

The problem is I cannot select a value in the combobox lists. I have also two hidden sheets that I do not want the combobox to populate.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub REFRESH_COMBOBOX1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
ComboBox1.Clear
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Visible Then ComboBox1.AddItem(ws.Name)
Next ws
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
REFRESH_COMBOBOX1
End Sub
```

Comment: You need a `ComboBox1.Clear` line before your loop - but I must also say your mousemove event is probably not the best way to fire a list refresh - can you not use a ComboBox1_Click() event or something instead?

Comment: @tinman I want the combobox lists updated whenever there's a changes on sheet names

Comment: There's no in-built way of registering whether a worksheet name has been changed so the simplest way is definitely to use `ComboBox1_Click()` to trigger a `ComboBox1.Clear` and then re-list every sheet name. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @jamheadart it worked but i cant select a value from my combobox lists..

Comment: @TinMan That doesn't register if you simply change a worksheet name though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you MUST use the DropButtonClick event then use this slightly different method of clearing the combobox:

```
Sub REFRESH_COMBOBOX1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Do While ComboBox1.ListCount > 0
    ComboBox1.RemoveItem (0)
Loop
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Visible Then ComboBox1.AddItem (ws.Name)
Next ws
End Sub
```

Instead of using the in-built `.Clear` function which will also remove the text inside the box, it will just remove items from the list and then re-add them

This means when you select an item, it won't be cleared even though the "REFRESH_COMBOBOX1" routine is called again.

Answer (score 1):

> combobox keeps adding the same sheet names when i move the mouse

Well, of course it does. You have an event procedure that's tied to moving the mouse, and your procedure is adding every sheet name to the list, with no check to see if the sheet already exist, etc. This should almost certainly be handled in a different event(s).

Probably, you want to populate this list from the form's `Activate` or `Initialize` event handler. So, somewhere in one of those methods, you'll call a procedure that clears & refreshes the `ComboBox`, like:

```
Call RefreshSheetList()
```

That function would look like so, and should be part of the User Form's code module:

```
Private Sub RefreshSheetList()
With ComboBox1
    .Clear
    For n=1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        .AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(n).Name
    Next n
End With
End Sub
```

If the form itself changes the environment (i.e., adds, renames or removes existing sheets) then the appropriate place to repopulate the `ComboBox` would be in the event handler that performs that action.

E.g., you have a `CommandButton1_Click` which adds a new sheet to the workbook (just as an example) then you would call it after the action has been performed, like so:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim w as Worksheet
With ActiveWorkbook
    Set w = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count))
    w.Name = Me.TextBox1.Text
End With
Call RefreshSheetList()
End Sub
```

Comment: it seems like you know what the problem is, or at least you have a better idea than I do, so, why don't you explain yourself fully? I can't read your mind.  there are many events tpu could subscribe to but I can't possibly know which might be best unless you give us the courtesy of explaining what your actual problem is.

Comment: if Clear is a problem, get rid of it. if you needed to keep it eg ro prevent duplicates etc, then you need to explain these things.  not in comments, but in revision to your original question.

Comment: OK, so you're using the DropDownButtonClick event, and that's probably not the right event to use. What was the problem with the `Enter` event in the other answer given here? That seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub REFRESH_COMBOBOX1() ' Routine for refreshing the list of names in box

    Dim ws As Worksheet     ' need a worksheet variable
    ComboBox1.Clear         ' clear the current list

  ' Cycle through every worksheet in the book, if it is NOT hidden then add name to list
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets    
        If ws.Visible Then ComboBox1.AddItem (ws.Name)  
    Next ws
End Sub ' 


' Separate routine to register the user putting focus on the box
' This happens every time the user clicks on or enters ComboBox1
Private Sub ComboBox1_Enter()
    REFRESH_COMBOBOX1 ' Calling the routine above
End Sub
```

Comment: @Tristan300 I see the issue here - in your code at the top you have used `ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()` where in my answer I've used `ComboBox1_Enter()`

Comment: If you use `ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()` you will see that the `REFRESH_COMBOBOX1` routine, which contains the line to `.Clear` gets called when you click the dropdown arrows, but ALSO when you select a value from the list - so you pick a name but clear it instantly as well. Use `Enter` instead

Comment: I cant use a enter event because im using it with other conditions and it gives me an error if i call the REFRESH_COMBOBOX in that event... Any other idea on just using the DropButtonClick event?

Comment: I've added another answer with a slightly different method of clearing and re-adding the items in the list.